# Convert String into Mixed List with Tuples and Integers

Tags: python, string, list

My application accepts user input as a string, like so...

```
"1;2;3;(4,5)"
```

I want this string to be converted into a list of integers and tuples like so...

```
[1,2,3,(4,5)]
```

How can I accomplish this in Python?

Comment: Have your tried splitting by `;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get the object from a string after splitting

```
import ast

in_str = "1;2;3;(4,5)"

output = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in in_str.split(';')]

print(output)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5)]
```

Comment: Perfect answer, I was just about to write it.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_str = "1;2;3;(4,5)"
str_list = input_str.split(';')
out_list = []
for item in str_list:
  if '(' in item:
    out_list.append(tuple([int(el) for el in item[1:-1].split(',')]))
  else:
    out_list.append(int(item))
print(out_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Would **not recommend** using `eval` if inputs can come from untrusted users. But if you trust your users, this may be a fine solution.

```
user_input = "1;2;3;(4,5)"
raw_list = user_input.split(';') # ['1', '2', '3', '(4,5)']
l = []
for item in raw_list:
  l.append(eval(item))
```

Then `l` contains the desired integers and tuples

```
l
>>> [1, 2, 3, (4, 5)]
```

---

**Method 2**

```
user_input = "1;2;3;(4,5)"
raw_list = user_input.split(';') # ['1', '2', '3', '(4,5)']
l = []
for item in raw_list:
  try:
    converted_item = int(item)
    l.append(converted_item)
  except ValueError:
    converted_item = tuple(map(int, item.strip("()").split(",")))
    l.append(converted_item)
```

Then `l` is the desired list.

```
l
>>> [1, 2, 3, (4, 5)]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No external modules needed, really:

```
string = "1;2;3;(4,5)"


def convert(item):
    try:
        x = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        x = tuple(convert(y) for y in item[1:-1].split(","))
    except:
        return item

    return x


lst = [convert(x) for x in string.split(";")]
print(lst)
```

This yields

```
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `split()` function :
`"1;2;3;(4,5)".split(';')`

Comment: This isn't complete. If you are going to post an answer, post a *full* answer.